# Как преобразовать строку int в uint (-1 4294967295) и наоборот?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "-1";  // или другое отриц.  
uint u = uint.Parse(s);  
// uint u = Convert.ToUInt32(s);
```

`Overflow` в любом случае.

Answer (score 5):

Ну для начала стоит прочитать что такое `uint`. Тут диапазон значений **От 0** до 4 294 967 295 ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/x0sksh43.aspx)). При конвертации числа вне диапазона значений в нужный тип - полученное число будет искажено/потеряно. 
 Если вас не беспокоит возможная потеря значения - используйте явное приведение 
типов:

```
uint a = 123;
int b = (int)a;
```

Comment: Ну для начала стоит прочитать вопрос.

Comment: ответ на вопрос дан. int  в uint преобразовать можно также как и в моем примере uint в int.. только с отрицательным значение возникнут проблемы.. возможно стоит выбрать другой тип. Ну или я не понял вопроса и вам стоит лучше объяснить проблему

Comment: число 11111111111111111111111111111110 будет -2 int или 4294967294 uint. Число представлено 'строкой'

Comment: вы за диапазон значений выходите - отсюда и проблема. Точно механизм не помню как оно считает, но когда доходит до предела диапазона - компилятор сбрасывает значение и читает следующие числа с начала диапазона.... в общем ничего нормального у вас с такими числами не будет - нужно использовать тип с большем расширением.. ну или хранить число частями в нескольких переменных